# How to check the ls version

Tags: shell

This topic is about the util 'ls'
The BSD version uses the parameter '-G' to color up the output,
while the Linux version uses parameter '--color'

Also the environment variable to set the colors is different:
BSD: $LSCOLORS
Linux: $LS_COLORS

But now the problem is: I want to determine which version is installed (using a small Shell script), so I can set alias ls and the environment appropriate in my .bachrc file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I mentioned above this seems to me to be the handiest method

```
if ls --color -d . >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    GNU_LS=1
elif ls -G -d . >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    BSD_LS=1
else
    SOLARIS_LS=1
fi
```

I've essentially this in my [l script](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/l), which I use on various platforms to tweak ls output as I like

Answer (score 4):

Just run 'ls' and see whether it throws an error, e.g. on my mac:

```
$ ls --color 1>/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
1
```

Whereas

```
$ ls -G 1>/dev/null 2>&1
$ echo $?
0
```

Indicating -G is supported, but --color is not.

Comment: ls --color -d . >/dev/null 2>&1 && gnu_ls=1 || bsd_ls=1

Comment: Maybe a stupid remark, but doesn't this cause a lot of overhead when the current directory contains many, many files? Or it that where the option '-d' is for?

Comment: @To1ne - not stupid, good call.  You could insert a suitable arg - maybe the root directory? - that will be found, and is unlikely to be full of many files.  Or you could create a temporary file and explicitly ls that (then remove it).  Or you could use /dev/null as the arg.  Agree that someting should be in there, rather than nothing.

Comment: Using it like pixelbeat suggested. But using `&>/dev/null` to redirect to the black hole.

Comment: -d just lists the directory not its contents. So now we've 4 comments explaining that rather than it being looked up/tried.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically, the `--version` switch Kimmo mentions is not supported on most BSD systems :-)

Writing a portable configuration file for your particular setup can be a Herculean task.  In your case, if you're sure your .bashrc is going to be used only on GNU/Linux and on a BSD system, you can check for switches that exist in one of the ls' but not in the other: for example, `-D` doesn't seem to be an accepted switch by ls on my BSD machines (FreeBSD and Mac OS X), whereas it is for GNU ls.  Conversely, `-P` is accepted on BSD, but not on GNU/Linux.  Knowing this, you can distinguish between the two ls' and set up environment variables accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 6.10
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Richard Stallman and David MacKenzie.
```

Comment: The version that ships with MacOSX doesn't support '--version' though

Comment: The lack of a version will tell you something too.  I don't have access to my Mac OSX box at the moment but you could try a `strings | grep version` if you can't get it using 'ls --version'.

Answer (score 0):

combining the methods described, here's an easy way to use a bash function instead of an alias in order to make colors work regardless of if you are using BSD or GNU `ls`.

```
ll () {
  if ls --version &>/dev/null; then
    ls --color=auto -lahtr
  else
    ls -Glahtr
  fi
}
```

inspired by a particular `conda` env recipe pulling in GNU `ls` on my macOS system where my `ls` aliases were all hard-coded for stock BSD `ls` only.